# Return the local currency code as per a users timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone

I am looking for a solution to get a users local currency code based on their timezone.

Using Stripe and Firebase I am creating a Firestore record upon Firebase `Auth`. When a user signs up, a `function` creates a database record containing the users timezone. Then also creating a customer inside Stripe.

To get the users timezone I am using `moment.tz.guess()` as supplied in the `moment-timezone` package. This is then saved to Firebase as a Firestore record.

The function is coded as

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{uid}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const customerValue = snap.data();
    const uid = context.params.uid;
    const timezone = moment.tz.guess();
    // const currencyCode = ;
    return stripe.customers
      .create({
        email: customerValue.email
      })
      .then(customer => {
        var customerObject = {
          id: customer.id,
          currencyCode,
        };
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .doc(`/users/${uid}/billing/${customer.id}`)
          .set(customerObject);
      });
  });
```

By default the customer is created in Stripe as USD. This is perfectly fine but using `timezone` is there an API or package to recognise the local currency code for the timezone. For example if the timezone returned from `moment` was `Australia/Adelaide`, how do I get `currencyCode` to return as `aud`?

One solution I came across was using **[country-tz-currency](https://github.com/anand6588/country-tz-currency#readme)** but I would first need to get the country code from the timezone and I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: These are time zones and not cities.  It's reasonable for me (America/Toronto) to pick any city in my time zone (America/New York for example).  But that doesn't give you the right currency.  Maybe ask the user which currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [this](https://ipstack.com/) API for my project, this not only will give you currency codes based on the country, also it will give some other useful data ( Like latitude & longitude , ... ) basically it's just a GET request which return an object of your user local location infos,  `Including continent_code`.

It have great documentation as well and the good thing is Up to 10.000 requests/m is free.